# Is it possible to construct sentences undecidable in first-order logic?

Tags: logic

I would like to know how to construct conjectures that cause automated first-order logic theorem provers to never terminate.
Is this possible in a general way, without targeting a specific automated theorem prover?

I know how to find some likely, but not proven, such sentences by searching for short formulas that cannot be solved within some reasonable time. I also know that the halting problem is undecidable, but I am hoping that the restriction to first-order logic theorem provers can be used, and I wonder if the solution is general or has to consider a specific theorem prover.

Examples of such short sentences in TPTP are welcome, here is a candidate tested with SPASS and E-prover:
fof(loop,conjecture, ?[X,Y,Z]: ((?[W]:r(Z, W)) => (r(X, Y) & r(Z, Y) & ~r(Z, X)))).

Comment: "Sentence unprovable" ? Every *invalid* sentence is unprovable : $\forall x Px$.

Comment: Changed to undecidable. Meant unprovable and irrefutable

Comment: See [two distinct senses of the word "undecidable"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem#Examples_of_undecidable_problems) : are you considering the first one : "a statement being neither provable nor refutable in a specified deductive system" ? If so, you have to specify : realtive to some mathematical theory, I suppose.

Comment: Since first-order logic itself is semi-decidable, I know that statements that can't be proved by a first-logic theorem prover exist, no further mathematical theory has to be involved. I am wondering if such statements can be constructed (using some stronger logic I suppose), and if so whether they can be constructed so that they cannot be decided in first-order logic in general, or a specific system (e.g. resolution) would have to be targeted for each construction.

Comment: Again, I am talking about invalid undecidable statements. Sorry for the omission.

Comment: Completeness : every *valid* sentence is provable. Thus, it is correct that there are first-order sentence s that can't be proved : all the *invalid* ones. Example : $\forall x Px$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA the prover still terminates with a refutation. I am interested in the cases where that doesn't happen (the prover has to run for ever). We know they exist. But are they specific to the prover's architecture? And can they be generated programmatically? (Obviously not using a first order theorem prover)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so you are talking about algorithms that take logic sentences and try to decide whether they are valid or invalid, and in particular you are looking for some fairly simple invalid sentences that will stump a 'standard' algorithm in that the algorithm fails to figure out that the sentence is indeed invalid.

Well, I would construct a sentence that can only be false with an infinite sized model. So, how about this:

$$\neg (\forall x\forall y\forall z((Rxy \land  Ryz)\rightarrow Rxz)\land \forall x \neg Rxx \land \forall x \exists y Ryx)$$

(Thanks Fabio for simplifying!)

In order for this statement to be false, all the conjuncts must be true. So, assuming there is at least one element $d_0$ in the domain (which most logics do .. and otherwise just throw in an existential), there needs to be some element $d_1$ such that $R[d_1,d_0]$ because of the $\forall x \exists y Ryx)$, and because of the $\forall x \neg Rxx$, $d_1$ cannot be the same as $d_0$. But now there needs to be an element $d_2$ such that $R[d_2,d_1]$, and this $d_2$ cannot be $d_1$ because of $\forall x \neg Rxx$, and it also cannot be $d_0$, because then we would have $R[d_1,d_0]$ as well as $R[d_0,d_1]$ and so by transitivity we would have $R[d_0,d_0]$ which would contradict $\forall x \neg Rxx$. Indeed, because of the transitivity and irreflexivity, each additional new element  keeps requiring a new element which can never be any of the previous elements, meaning that you need an infinite sized domain to satisfy the  conjunction and thus make the statement as a whole false.

In fact, it is easy to see that there *is* an infinite sized counterexample since we can interpret $Rxy$ as '$x$ > $y$' for the natural numbers, which will indeed make the conjunction true, and thus the statement false. But since typical algorithms for checking the validity of sentences (e.g. truth-tree based algorithms) will only find finite sized counterexamples, I bet this sentence will stump quite a few of the existing checkers.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused because I was playing with a couple of *satisfiability* checkers.  I deleted my comment as soon as I realized that, but unfortunately, not soon enough.  Incidentally, the checkers are Z3 and CVC4.  They don't build a semantic tableau, as far as I know, but they use heuristic quantifier instantiation. They get stumped by your example as well as the simpler request to prove that there is no structure that satisfies the antecedent.

Comment: @Bram28 your description of my question is exactly right. Let me ruminate a bit on your answer before accepting. Thanks!

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Interesting!  I am actually quite unfamiliar with any existing checkers, so thanks for letting me know. And yes, the consequent in my example is inconsequential, so I could simplfy it. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: E and SPASS also seem to get stumped. I see however that the answer to my secondary question on whether there can be a general method, has to be (trivially) negative, since one could hardcode your sentence into the prover and be able to come up with a result. So unless we know what tricks the solver might have hardcoded, it may be able to solve any (but not all) problem we throw at it.

Comment: I think even this is sufficient: ¬(∀x∀y∀z((Rxy∧Ryz)→Rxz)∧∀x∃yRyx)

Comment: This is very weird, since even R[d0,d0] contradicts this, yet E and SPASS seem stumped. This is how I write it: fof(loop,conjecture, ~( (![X,Y,Z]: ((r(X,Y) & r(Y,Z)) => r(X,Z))) & (![X]:(?[Y]: r(Y,X))))).

Answer (score 0):

First-order logic itself is semi-decidable, and it is not hard to create an automated theorem prover that, given some first-order logic sentence, will eventually prove any valid sentence to be valid.  In fact, I assume many automated theorem provers will have this feature, so I wouldn't count on there being unprovable and irrefutable sentences for automated theorem provers in general, when the domain is first-order logic itself.

Once we move to mathematics, things quickly become undecidable in theory, and even more quickly undecidable in practice. Here we can of course point to any open problem in mathematics, and presumably no theorem prover will be able to either prove it or disprove it. The Goldbach conjecture (every even number greater than 2 is the sum of two prime numbers) can be stated with a fairly short first-order logic expression, and that one will stump any automated theorem prover on the market assuming, of course, that the theorem prover is knowably sound (I throw in the 'knowable' to prevent anyone to simply make Goldbach's Conjecture an axiom). And while Fermat's theorem (also easily stated in first-order logic) has been mathematically proven, I highly doubt that at this point any (sound) existing theorem prover can prove it.

Comment: That is true, but I was not clear enough. I am not asking for valid sentences that are undecidable in the Godel sense. I am interested in constructing invalid sentences that cannot be refuted by the theorem prover. Since first-order logic is semideciable, we know such sentences exist, but I can't just pick any invalid sentence, because theorem provers may prove its negation, thus refuting it. I am asking about how to construct such invalid sentences that cannot be refuted, preferrably in some mechanical way and being as concise as possible.

Comment: Actually, even if the theorem prover cannot prove a statement, neither its negation, it may terminate with an answer to the effect: "No proof found" I am interested in creating simple cases where this doesn't happen and the prover is guaranteed to run for ever (in principle).

Comment: @Akuri Ah! OK, I have a suggestion I'll add to my Answer.

Comment: @Akuri How could you possibly prevent a theorem prover from returning "no proof found" after a certain amount of time has elapsed?  If a program sets an alarm and quits when it gets the corresponding signal, there isn't much you can do.  And that is far from unheard of.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Yeah, you're right, many if not most provers will have a time or step threshold ... but not all!

Comment: @FabioSomenzi I can prevent it from terminating by running it on an ideal Turing machine with infinite memory:) That is why I say run for ever *in principle*. Of course in practice it would hit memory limits eventually, but please don't consider this possibility.

Comment: @Bram28 if Fermat's theorem is easily stated in first-order-logic and is a valid theorem (since it has been proven), and since FOL is semi-decideable, an ideal first-order theorem prover would eventually prove it and terminate (maybe after a million years, but still). I am interested in understanding the remaining cases that would make even a prover with infinite resources to never terminate.

Comment: @Akuri Remember the difference between proving things about pure logic vs proving things about mathematics: mathematical theorems are not logical truths, but rather logically follow from mathematical axioms. So, if we don;t provide the necessary axioms, a theorem prover will not able able to prove Fermat's last theorem, even if the prover is complete with regard to pure logic (and that's only first-order logic at that!). The fact that it has been proven mathematically is no guarantee that a prover has all the axioms in place.

Comment: @Bram28 Indeed. If the mathematical axioms are not axiom schemata (finately axiomatizable theory), could we merge them into an implication (Axioms => Theorem) which would itself be a valid first order sentence in pure logic? Of course Peano number theory is not finately axiomatizable.

Comment: @Akuri Yes, all the "Axioms => Theorem" statements will be logically valid statements, but you would still need to have all those Axioms in place. And as you say, in first-order logic, we can't even express general axiom schemas like the Induction schema.