# First order logic: Finding an interpretation that makes H true in the integer domain

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'm trying to solve this exercise but I'm stuck. I have to consider the following set of formulas H:

∀x∃y(Rx,y)

¬∃x(Rx,x)

∀x∀y∀z(Rx,y∧Ry,z→Rx,z)

I have to show an interpretation that makes H true in the Integer domain.

My biggest issue is that I don't understand how to start the construction of the interpretation. What should I look for? Any useful theoremes/rules?

Comment: What about $<$ to interpret $R$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are looking for a $2$-place relationship on the integers.  The first one that comes to my mind is $<$.  And lo and behold, that one works:

$∀x∃y(Rx,y)$ becomes $∀x∃y (x < y)$, i.e. for every integer there is a greater integer. Yes, that's true!

$¬∃x(Rx,x)$ becomes $¬∃x(x<x)$. i.e. there is no integer smaller than itself. Also true!

$∀x∀y∀z(Rx,y∧Ry,z→Rx,z)$ becomes $∀x∀y∀z(x<y∧y<z→x<z)$, i.e. whenever a first integer is smaller than a second, and that second is smaller than a third, then the first is smaller than the third.  Again: True!

Comment: Now I understand, thank you very much. I've an other doubt: after that you find this interpretation, you have to demonstrate that H isn't satisfiable in any non empty and finite domain. Do you have any hints for this part too? thank you

Comment: @shepard See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2069404/is-it-possible-to-construct-sentences-undecidable-in-first-order-logic/2070386#2070386